# How can I convert px units to em units programmatically in vim?

Tags: css, regex, vim

I'd like to move away from using `px` units in my CSS and move towards using `em` units. [This page](http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/css/pixels-to-ems/) has a formula for the conversion that's `1/16*X` where 16 is the base font size in pixels, and X is the font size to be converted. With that in mind, I tried doing something like:

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)px/\=1\/16*submatch(1)."em"/gc
```

but it's not working as expected. This is my first time using expressions in vim substitutions, so I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have changed your substitution to the following:

```
:%s#\v(\d+)px#\=printf("%0.3fem", 1.0/16*submatch(1))#gc
```

Details

- Use `#` for delimiters instead of `/` to make it easier to read and fix division
- `\v` to turn on very magic to make the regex a bit more readable (preference)
- Must use `Floats` because Vim's `Number` format will truncate when dividing. e.g. `1/16` vs `1.0/16`
- `Floats` and concatenations do not mix so use `printf` to put together the string
- Use format `%0.3f` to ensure a leading zero and 3 digits after the decimal

For more information see:

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h submatch(
:h /\v
:h Float
:h Number
:h E806
:h printf(
```

Comment: So awesome. This is the first I've learned about `\v`, too, which I'm sure will save me a lot of typing and headaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the suggestions above, I went ahead and created a Vim Plugin to make this easier to use! It's as easy as it gets by using the commands

```
:Em
```

or

```
:Px
```

https://github.com/chiedojohn/vim-px-to-em

Answer (score 0):

What you want is described under `:h sub-replace-special`

Having read that, you basically need to adjust your replace part to

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)px/\=1\/\=16*submatch(1)."em"/gc
```

Comment: What does the second `\=` do? Apart from this would this cause a Float to String error (E806)? `1/16` yields `0` because they are not floats, wouldn't it be best to start with a float e.g `1.0/16`? This is what I came up with: `%s#\v(\d+)px#\=printf("%0.3fem", 1.0/16*submatch(1))#gc`

Comment: @PeterRincker, the code in your comment works. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah I missed the first `/` and took the \=1 for `\=`. Sorry for not reading correctly.